# NSDateFormatter starts in 2000, but NSDate starts in 2001

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

Does anyone know why `NSDateFormatter` starts in 2000, but NSDate starts in 2001?

`let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:0)` is 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001

but a `NSDateFormatter` that converts minutes (for example 11:00) to a NSDate, returns 2000-01-01 11:00:00 UTC

How is that possible?

Comment: Why does it matter? You can set `formatter.defaultDate` to get a well-defined behavior when parsing “incomplete” dates.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR
That works, but still it is very strange this behaviour in 2 methods from the same API.

Comment: (NS)DateFormatter goes back to CFDateFormatter, which – as one can see in the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744/CFDateFormatter.c.auto.html) – uses the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org). There is no reason to assume that ICU and  (Apple's) NSDate use the same reference date.

Comment: I had no idea about that. Thanks a lot.